# Computing hypergeometric function at 1

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, hypergeometric-functions

I'm looking to compute

$${}_ 3F_ 2\biggl(\begin{matrix} -m-1/2,\ -m,\ k-m+1/2 \cr
1/2-m,\ k-m+3/2\end{matrix};1\biggr)$$

for $m,k > 0$ are positive integers and $0 < k < m$. I'm wondering if there is any reduction that can be applied, such as Thomae's theorem, which is mentioned in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29829/a-known-hypergeometric-identity) (though I don't think I can apply it here).

I would also be interested in any reductions, or if this evaluation was $0$ or had a definite sign like $(-1)^m$.
Apologies in advance as I am a geometric analyst looking to compute things with [eigenfunctions of the laplacian](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/460349/closed-form-ode-solutions-for-jacobi-field-eigenfunction-of-laplacian-on-hyperbo) on the hyperbolic disk - any references there would also be useful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For questions like this, Mathematica is your friend:

$$\, _3F_2\left(-m-\tfrac{1}{2},-m,k-m+\tfrac{1}{2};\tfrac{1}{2}-m,k-m+\tfrac{3}{2};1\right)$$
$$=\tfrac{1}{2}(k+1)^{-1}\Gamma (m+1) \left(\frac{(2 k-2 m+1) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}-m\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}+\frac{(2 m+1) \Gamma \left(k-m+\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\Gamma \left(k+\frac{3}{2}\right)}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I was woefully unaware that Mathematica could do these computations

Comment: it is always smart to not blindly trust the output, I typically insert a few values to check the identity in the parameter range where it is needed; in the past I would use reference books, which may have typo's, so the situation is not that different.

Comment: Interestingly, you can even get this from the online free version [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=HypergeometricPFQ%5B%7B-m-1%2F2%2C+-m%2C+k-m%2B1%2F2%7D%2C+%7B1%2F2-m%2Ck-m%2B3%2F2%7D%2C1%5D) just entering the expression "HypergeometricPFQ[{-m-1/2, -m, k-m+1/2}, {1/2-m,k-m+3/2}, 1]"

Comment: certainly, the functionality is the same, the restrictions are mainly on the time needed for the computation.

Answer (score 15):

Carlo's answer is correct but doesn't show why the identity holds, so let me explain how to do this easily by hand.

Look more generally at
$$S={}_3F_2\left(\begin{matrix}-m,a,b\\a+1,b+1\end{matrix};1\right).$$
The terms involve the factor
$$\frac{(a)_k(b)_k}{(a+1)_k(b+1)_k}=\frac{ab}{(a+k)(b+k)}=\frac{ab}{b-a}\left(\frac{1}{a+k}-\frac{1}{b+k}\right)
=\frac{1}{b-a}\left(\frac{b(a)_k}{(a+1)_k}-\frac{a(b)_k}{(b+1)_k}\right).$$
Hence,
$$S=\frac{b}{b-a}\,{}_2F_1\left(\begin{matrix}-m,a\\a+1\end{matrix};1\right)-
\frac{a}{b-a}\,{}_2F_1\left(\begin{matrix}-m,b\\b+1\end{matrix};1\right).
$$
These sums are computed by the Chu-Vandermonde summation and we obtain
$$S=\frac{m!}{b-a}\left(\frac{b}{(a+1)_m}-\frac{a}{(b+1)_m}\right).$$
Your sum is a special case of this. Since your sum is finite, it is of course a rational expression, you really shouldn't write it in terms of $\sqrt{\pi}$ etc. like Mathematica.

Comment: Thank you for the derivation - it is quite clever! It also seems that to convert to Carlos' answer I could use the Gauss summation from the second to last equation.

Comment: @JMK Yes, and it also follows that if we drop the condition that $m$ is a non-negative integer, then the sum of the series is
$$\frac{\Gamma(m+1)}{b-a}\left(\frac{b\,\Gamma(a+1)}{\Gamma(a+1+m)}-\frac{a\,\Gamma(b+1)}{\Gamma(b+1+m)}\right),$$
subject to convergence conditions.